# How can I set dynamically created bitmap as livefolder icon in android?

Tags: android, icons, shortcut

How can I set dynamically created bitmap as livefolder icon in android?

LiveFolder takes EXTRA_LIVE_FOLDER_ICON as ShortcutIconResource. Is there a way to reference dynamically created bitmap as shortcuticonresource? In the following code segment instead of using icon as int value I would like to set the file path for the newly created bitmap file.

```
intent.putExtra(LiveFolders.EXTRA_LIVE_FOLDER_ICON,
                 Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, icon));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use bitmap from a file in a live folder.